# Is it crazy to Auto Layout everything in code?

Tags: ios, layout, view, autolayout, uikit

I lay everything out in code, and like the control and ability to copy code easily (when reusability doesn't make sense). I do use lightweight wrappers around NSLayoutConstraint to cut down on verbosity, but I noticed that my files are pretty large because of the required instantiate-then-layout structure for every single view.

Is this crazy? Is using storyboards/XIBs better/faster?

Answer (score 1):

I lay out my views -and their subviews- in code, so I belong to the same school you come from. But as a fellow scholar, take a look at `UIStackView`, it will save you tons of `NSLayoutConstraints` work, since you basically place everything as a subview of the StackView -without worrying about constraints-, then *only* work on the constraints of the StackView in relation to its superView. You still need to work on the UIStackView properties, but it's nothing compared to having to work on layoutConstraints of every single subView of any given view.

I believe there is a 101 ways to skin an app, code, Interface Builder, 3rd party stuff, I don't believe anyone who say their way is the right way -or that someone else's is wrong-, it's simply different schools of life, and some developers are simply code masochists.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion question, but I'll weigh in anyway. I'm a senior/lead iOS developer, and I think that aside from doing it as a learning exercise, or in limited cases where there's a good reason, doing your view layout and Auto Layout in code is a very bad idea, and I would not hire somebody who insists on doing it that way.

It's more work in the first place, and much more work to maintain.

Comment: This ^. There are some cases where you will want to do it, where having it as an exercise will give you the ability judge those corner cases, but I swore off of doing it in code as the default after I ported my project to swift, and have never been happier.

Using a 3rd party thing to make it easier to do in code sounds like an utter nightmare come upgrade time.

Comment: This is a terrible answer - you should have just voted to close as "primarily opinion-based". There is no one correct way to write an app. While autolayout is not the correct choice for some applications (e.g. games, complete custom interfaces) it can absolutely be the correct way for utility apps.

Answer (score 0):

If it is written with the code I agree to the opinion of use Masonry(Objective-C) or SnapKit(Swift)

Visual Format Language may also be simple

Xib or storyboard constraints are not suitable for multiplayer development

If personal development xib or storyboard is also a good choice

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use Masonry(Objective-C) or SnapKit(Swift) replace NSLayoutConnstrant

Comment: it is not a good way to answer the question